# 2D points to SVG or PDF file in Java

Tags: java, pdf, svg, canvas, 2d

Want to convert 2D points of canvas to svg or pdf file.

{
"points":[{"x":158,"y":786},{"x":158,"y":781},{"x":158,"y":764},{"x":158,"y":754},{"x":158,"y":743},{"x":158,"y":717},{"x":158,"y":699},{"x":158,"y":678},{"x":158,"y":631},{"x":160,"y":606},{"x":163,"y":583},{"x":171,"y":531},{"x":173,"y":505},{"x":176,"y":480},{"x":184,"y":428},{"x":184,"y":413},{"x":184,"y":406},{"x":188,"y":372},{"x":193,"y":348},{"x":197,"y":333},{"x":197,"y":303},{"x":199,"y":284},{"x":201,"y":277},{"x":201,"y":269},{"x":201,"y":260},{"x":201,"y":256},{"x":201,"y":243},{"x":201,"y":236},{"x":201,"y":234},{"x":201,"y":230},{"x":201,"y":228},{"x":201,"y":234},{"x":201,"y":238},{"x":203,"y":240},{"x":206,"y":243},{"x":210,"y":251},{"x":211,"y":255},{"x":214,"y":260},{"x":227,"y":273},{"x":231,"y":281},{"x":236,"y":290},{"x":253,"y":325},{"x":257,"y":334},{"x":270,"y":359},{"x":288,"y":398},{"x":293,"y":413},{"x":296,"y":419},{"x":309,"y":450},{"x":317,"y":471},{"x":322,"y":484},{"x":335,"y":514},{"x":344,"y":536},{"x":348,"y":544},{"x":357,"y":566},{"x":360,"y":573},{"x":361,"y":575},{"x":365,"y":596},{"x":372,"y":607},{"x":374,"y":609},{"x":378,"y":618},{"x":382,"y":622},{"x":383,"y":622},{"x":383,"y":626},{"x":386,"y":630},{"x":387,"y":631},{"x":387,"y":635},{"x":387,"y":637},{"x":387,"y":639},{"x":391,"y":639},{"x":395,"y":635},{"x":395,"y":635},{"x":188,"y":514},{"x":193,"y":514},{"x":201,"y":514},{"x":201,"y":514},{"x":210,"y":514},{"x":223,"y":514},{"x":224,"y":514},{"x":236,"y":514},{"x":242,"y":514},{"x":249,"y":514},{"x":257,"y":514},{"x":258,"y":514},{"x":266,"y":514},{"x":270,"y":514},{"x":270,"y":514},{"x":272,"y":514},{"x":275,"y":514},{"x":277,"y":514},{"x":279,"y":514},{"x":292,"y":506},{"x":302,"y":495},{"x":309,"y":488},{"x":326,"y":475},{"x":331,"y":470},{"x":335,"y":467},{"x":348,"y":454},{"x":356,"y":451},{"x":361,"y":450},{"x":365,"y":441},{"x":371,"y":438},{"x":374,"y":437},{"x":377,"y":437},{"x":378,"y":437},{"x":380,"y":437},{"x":378,"y":432},{"x":374,"y":432},{"x":374,"y":432},{"x":426,"y":337},{"x":426,"y":350},{"x":426,"y":368},{"x":426,"y":394},{"x":426,"y":403},{"x":426,"y":419},{"x":426,"y":458},{"x":426,"y":477},{"x":426,"y":497},{"x":426,"y":510},{"x":426,"y":526},{"x":426,"y":549},{"x":426,"y":583},{"x":426,"y":597},{"x":426,"y":609},{"x":426,"y":613},{"x":426,"y":620},{"x":426,"y":626},{"x":426,"y":635},{"x":426,"y":638},{"x":426,"y":639},{"x":426,"y":643},{"x":426,"y":645},{"x":426,"y":645},{"x":525,"y":480},{"x":525,"y":475},{"x":521,"y":480},{"x":515,"y":482},{"x":512,"y":484},{"x":499,"y":493},{"x":493,"y":498},{"x":490,"y":501},{"x":477,"y":506},{"x":467,"y":512},{"x":464,"y":514},{"x":460,"y":514},{"x":454,"y":517},{"x":452,"y":518},{"x":443,"y":523},{"x":440,"y":526},{"x":439,"y":527},{"x":434,"y":527},{"x":431,"y":527},{"x":434,"y":523},{"x":439,"y":523},{"x":441,"y":523},{"x":443,"y":523},{"x":447,"y":523},{"x":452,"y":528},{"x":456,"y":531},{"x":469,"y":540},{"x":476,"y":547},{"x":482,"y":553},{"x":499,"y":566},{"x":512,"y":579},{"x":521,"y":587},{"x":538,"y":600},{"x":550,"y":613},{"x":555,"y":618},{"x":559,"y":622},{"x":569,"y":633},{"x":572,"y":635},{"x":581,"y":639},{"x":584,"y":646},{"x":585,"y":648},{"x":590,"y":652},{"x":593,"y":652},{"x":594,"y":652},{"x":594,"y":656},{"x":594,"y":658},{"x":598,"y":656},{"x":598,"y":661},{"x":598,"y":661},{"x":598,"y":664},{"x":598,"y":664},{"x":628,"y":350},{"x":628,"y":355},{"x":628,"y":368},{"x":628,"y":385},{"x":628,"y":388},{"x":628,"y":411},{"x":628,"y":437},{"x":628,"y":446},{"x":628,"y":467},{"x":628,"y":506},{"x":628,"y":519},{"x":628,"y":518},{"x":628,"y":553},{"x":628,"y":556},{"x":628,"y":562},{"x":628,"y":575},{"x":628,"y":580},{"x":628,"y":587},{"x":628,"y":592},{"x":628,"y":594},{"x":628,"y":596},{"x":628,"y":598},{"x":633,"y":579},{"x":633,"y":579},{"x":736,"y":708},{"x":736,"y":712},{"x":736,"y":712},{"x":628,"y":531},{"x":633,"y":531},{"x":636,"y":531},{"x":637,"y":531},{"x":640,"y":531},{"x":641,"y":531},{"x":646,"y":531},{"x":648,"y":531},{"x":650,"y":531},{"x":651,"y":531},{"x":654,"y":531},{"x":659,"y":531},{"x":663,"y":531},{"x":667,"y":531},{"x":672,"y":531}],

"height":1548,
"width":1536
}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can only be converted to a path in a svg, and not at all to a pdf, unless made into a graphic first. SVG-generating code:

```
public static String generatePath(String input, boolean closePath) {
    Pattern vertexPattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\\"x\\\"\\:(\\d+),\\\"y\\\"\\:(\\d+)\\}");
    Matcher matcher = vertexPattern.matcher(input);
    List<Point> points = new LinkedList<>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        int y = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
        points.add(new Point(x, y));
    }

    String template = "<svg width=\"100\" height=\"100\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">"
            + "<path d=\"%s\"/>"
            + "</svg>";
    Point previousPoint = null;
    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(256);
    for (Point point : points) {
        if (previousPoint == null || (previousPoint.x != point.x && previousPoint.y != point.y)) {
            path.append(previousPoint == null ? "M " : " L ").append(point.x).append(" ").append(point.y);
        } else if (previousPoint.x != point.x) {
            path.append(" H ").append(point.x);
        } else if (previousPoint.y != point.y) {
            path.append(" V ").append(point.y);
        } else {
            // no actual distance is passed.
        }
        previousPoint = point;
    }
    if (closePath) {
        path.append(" Z");
    }
    return String.format(template, path.toString());
}
```

This code will take your input (the one you presented) and convert it into a **path**. However, you still need to add information as to what to do with the path, like color and so forth. For that, you can modify the template string.

Comment: A `<polyline>` or `<polygon>` is probably a more appropriate element to use here instead of a `<path>`.  The path will work tho.